# Tweetinvi AuthFlow.InitAuthentication - how to set ProxyURL

Tags: twitter, proxy, twitter-oauth, tweetinvi

I am having trouble at this line -

```
var authenticationContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(applicationCredentials, callBackURL);
```

From our app servers internet calls are restricted. 
After setting a proxy url, I can browse twitter website on IE browser.

Now the puzzle is how to set the proxy to succeed the above code snippet in TweetInvi object. I tried setting a valid proxy using this property -

```
TweetinviConfig.ApplicationSettings.ProxyURL
```

But, still I get Timedout error. 
Is there a way to set the proxy url to make calls to Twitter success?

> exception Message: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token web
>   request timed out.

Web exception Stack trace:

> at
>   Tweetinvi.Credentials.WebTokenFactory.LogExceptionOrThrow(TwitterException
>   ex) at
>   Tweetinvi.Credentials.WebTokenFactory.InitAuthenticationProcess(IConsumerCredentials
>   appCredentials, String callbackURL, Boolean updateQueryIsAuthorized)
>   at
>   Thomson.Financial.Thomlets.Economics.Web.PublishTwitter.GetAutherizeFromTwitter()

Comment: Can you provide the format you used for the proxy? Does the proxy requires a username/password?

Comment: I tried - TweetinviConfig.ApplicationSettings.ProxyURL = "http://webproxy.lon.corp.services:80"; And this proxy doesn't require username/password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProxyURL` propoerty did not work. I made changes to Web.config of the actual application to use the proxy. 
Make the below changes to web.config so that the servers can access the internet -

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="true" proxyaddress="<proxy address>" bypassonlocal="true" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Comment: I am happy that you find a solution for your problem. I will make sure to add this to the documentation.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but could you confirm that your project is an ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, its an ASP.NET web application

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hope Tweetinvi is helping you in what you are trying to achieve :)